# How to get the inside div element child and handle event in extjs4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, extjs

```
I want to select the div with class "icon-right" and add the click event.
    Html code:
        <div class="msg"> 
           <div> 
               <div class="sample"></div> 
           </div>
           <div> 
              <div class="icon-right"></div> 
           </div> 
        </div>
    I want to select the div which has class icon-right and handle click event..
    Extjs code:
        var message = Ext.select('div:next(div.icon-right)');

        message.on('click', function () {
            alert('test msg');
        }, message);
```

But i need to change the div with class icon-right as div with icon-left when on click and now when i click the icon-left it change to div with class icon-right.. vice versa happens

Answer (score 0):

Can you do:

```
Ext.select('.icon-right').up('div').on('click', function() {});
```

Comment: k but I need to select the div which has the class icon-right and add event func on it

Comment: @user2721034 see my answer for a functional solution.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald it not working. actually i remove the div with class 'icon-right' and embed div with class 'icon-left'. when i click the div with icon-left class the click event happens. When on click i change the div with 'icon-right'. viceversa.

Comment: But i need to change the div with class icon-right as div with icon-left when on click and now when i click the icon-left it change to div with class icon-right.. vice versa happens

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext-method-select), Ext.select returns a [CompositeElement](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.dom.CompositeElement) or a *collection* of DOM elements. You should be using [Ext.query](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext-method-query) which will return an HTMLElement, which you can then define the `onclick` event handler:

```
var target = Ext.query(".icon-right").pop(); // return the first div of the query
target.onclick = function(){ alert('clicked!'); }
```

Alternatively, if you wish to utilize Ext event listeners, you must make use of the [Ext.dom.Element class](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element), an instance of which is returned by `Ext.get`, which calls for an ID, DOM Node or Existing Element [as per the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext-method-get). If you were to retrieve the element via `Ext.get`, you could then assign a listener via [`Ext.dom.Element.on`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-on) as you have in the provided code.

**Working jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/LcRWB/ (shows both examples)

Comment: it not working. actually i remove the div with class 'icon-right' and embed div with class 'icon-left'. when i click the div with icon-left class the click event happens. When on click i change the div with 'icon-right'. viceversa.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, my answer addressed your original question and provided two working solutions. Now that you have completely changed the scope of your original question, how do you expect any of the answers to still be applicable?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var el = Ext.Element.select("[class=icon-right]");
el.on('click', function() {
  alert("hi");
});
```

You can see an example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XzKKZ/

Comment: it not working. actually i remove the div with class 'icon-right' and embed div with class 'icon-left'. when i click the div with icon-left class the click event happens. When on click i change the div with 'icon-right'. viceversa.